# How to explain the behaviour of tyre smoke

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics

Please forgive me for being a non-phycisist and new member. I am working on a Visual Effects module for my degree and I need to analyse the behaviour of tyre smoke from a burnout. I know that this concerns fluid dynamics and thermodynamics, but as a non-scientist, I have researched the topic as best I can and do not really know where to start beyond a visual description of what is happening. Can anyone help with any simple formulas to explain the behaviour of smoke? Or refer me to some relevent information that is beginner level? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Behaviour in what sense? How it's created, dispersed by wind, behaves in an enclosed space, how to enhance or reduce it or what? Anyway, best of luck with your question.

Comment: If you are able to take a look at this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cRWX7O9gR9A&index=7&list=PLP6HxYakLGtjS1jWqQq8iDDIFCSzTKSuO I have to analyse that footage for how the smoke behaves in order to simulate it as a visual effect, so, yes, creation, movement and how it is dispersed, and what forces are acting upon it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it probably belongs on World Building SE.

Comment: Simulation using the equations of fluid dynamics will be too difficult for a non-physicist (and non-mathematician?) and require far too much computing power. If you only want to reproduce a visual effect, it is better to try to *imitate* it, starting from a very rough approximation and gradually refining it, and introducing some random effects. You can study how the smoke develops and disperses simply by watching it. You must know of some techniques eg for imitating human or animal motion. If the project were to simulate the flight of a bird, what equations would you use then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to say I don't really think this is a physics question, but..

From [Smoke Production](https://www.carthrottle.com/post/if-you-think-tyres-produce-smoke-during-a-burnout-youre-wrong/)

> when you’re drifting or doing a burnout, you’re not actually creating ‘smoke’.
>   When you get the tyre spinning, the friction between the tyre and the tarmac superheats the rubber to as much as 400 degrees (though this does depend on the length of the burnout). This melts the rubber tread, vapourising the chemicals and oil within it, sending these molecules into the air. The vapourised molecules then cool quickly and condense in the air, becoming the visible white ‘smoke’ you see - it’s actually more like steam than smoke, though.
>   So there you have it; tyre smoke isn’t really smoke at all, it’s just billions upon billions of vapourised molecules from a tyre’s rubber, oil and chemical makeup.

My best (obvious)  guesses:

Creation depends on type of rubber compound, width of tyre, speed of rotation - smoke does not start immediately, the tyre has to reach particular  melting point of rubber compound. Any volatile compounds on tyre would enhance the smoke, oil would be ideal, but kinda risky.

In your video, it looked to me like the exhaust put out as much smoke as the tyres, either that or they **really** smoke.

Movement: assume wind direction is from front to rear of car, study YouTube videos in two areas, 1. Wind tunnel tests and 2. Photoshop effects ( which I am sure you know about),

Forces acting on it are 99.9% wind  related, the smoke particles are tiny, compared to other sources and without wind, I reckon they would stay put around the source.

There is nothing else off hand I can think of, sorry. The picture below is a photoshop image, see where the smoke collects, between the type and the tyre well/body work.

[image]

Image source : YouTube

And now a real car.

[image]

Image Source: From [Smoke Production](https://www.carthrottle.com/post/if-you-think-tyres-produce-smoke-during-a-burnout-youre-wrong/)

Comment: Best of luck with it, tell me when the movie comes out.

Comment: Haha, I will! Would it be fair to say that the vapour behaves as a turbulent fluid?

Comment: Sammy's comments above are spot on, trying to actually create a physically model with turbulence  would involve the Navier-Stokes equations, which you don't want to know about, seriously. Technically, a fluid is either gas or liquid, but in this case, because steam is mentioned, I would go with the much lower density (lightness if you will) of a gas.